# phoneGap Build not copying over icon.png and other icons for iPhone

Tags: iphone, angularjs, phonegap-build

I am having an issue with inconsistent behavior in copying over icons for the IOS build. Specifically, the default icons are not being copied over, but other images (version 6.0) are.

the layout of the phonegap build folder structure is
root
 - res
  - icon
   - ios
    - *.png
  - screen
 - app
   - (angular folders)
 - content
 - css
 - img
 - js
index.html
config.xml
*.png

This works locally (and shows icons as expected) when I load into my dev iPad, but gets refused by apple review process.

the log file is here: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1415919/logs/ios/build/
the compiled files are here: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1415919/share

```
    <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.mbienergyservices.employment" version="1.0.0">
  <name>MBI Works!</name>
  <description>Find your career at MBI</description>
  <author href="http://mbienergyservices.com" email="support@mbienergyservices.com">James Fleming</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />  
    <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" />
 <platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project --> 
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
  <!-- icon --> 
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<!-- iOS legacy --> 
<!-- iPhone -->       
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>

<!-- iPhone 6 / 6plus -->
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 --> 
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->  
<icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/> 
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />     
</platform>
<icon src="icon.png"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <!-- splash -->
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>

<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>  

<!-- iPad -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<!-- iPhone 6 -->   
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />
<!-- Retina iPad -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

  <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I think the issue was I had the icons inside the platform tags.

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.mbienergyservices.employment" version="1.0.0">
  <name>MBI Works!</name>
  <description>Find your career at MBI</description>
  <author href="http://mbienergyservices.com" email="support@mbienergyservices.com">James Fleming</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>

    <platform name="ios">
      <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
      <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
      <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
      <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
      <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
      <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
    </platform>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />  
    <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" />
 <platform name="android"></platform>

    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project --> 
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
  <!-- icon --> 
 <icon src="icon.png"/>
<!-- iOS legacy --> 
<!-- iPhone -->       
<icon src="www/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" />
<icon src="www/icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="www/icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>

<!-- iPhone 6 / 6plus -->
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="www/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="www/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="www/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="www/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 --> 
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->  
<icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/> 
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>

    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <!-- splash -->
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>

<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>  

<!-- iPad -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<!-- iPhone 6 -->   
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />
<!-- Retina iPad -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

  <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
</widget>
```